# Setting default global background color for all view controllers via Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder

I'm trying to set a default background color for all view controllers via the Interface Builder, so when I build them I will see how they are going to look on the device.

Comment: I can't see a way of doing so via IB, apart from manually setting each VC's background color one at a time...

Answer (score 1):

You can have all your view controllers extend a base view controller which has the default background color overriden in its **viewDidLoad**.

Comment: I asked about doing it via the interface builder so I will be able to see how it looks

Answer (score 0):

There is something like `IBInspectable` and `IBDesignable` which may help you. Please refer: http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Comment: Those are nice things but since I can't make all of my `UIView` to be `IBDesignable` they can't help me achieve what I want to acheive